# Impossible to delete files in Windows 10 from InstallAware Studio

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have some folders that InstallAware has used as output directories for building installers for some of our software. InstallAware copies from system dll's into the output directory to be packaged with the install, so you get some directories like this:

`\Release\Single\data\OFFLINE\7F8A918D\BCE51B05\twinapi.appcore.dll`
and
`\Release\Single\data\OFFLINE\8A864189\BCE51B05\ntasn1.dll`

Now the problem is these output directories are fully impossible to delete. The OS seems to think these files copied *from* System32 are the actual system dll's that should never be deleted.

In general, the reason I cannot delete those dll's is that they are in use by `dwm.exe` or `Desktop Window Manager`. Other processes that are allegedly using these dll files: Windows Explorer (though ending this and attempting to delete has no effect), wlanext.exe, WUDFHost.exe, csrss.exe...

Essentially, the manner in which these dll's would be used in their actual location (System32 generally), the OS thinks these files are being used in that same way. I should also mention there are 15-20 of these folders, with 15-20 copies of all these DLL's, and Windows thinks every single one of them is being used simultaneously by the system processes mentioned above.

These files are located on the Desktop, in temporary output folders used by InstallAware to package files for making an installer.

Anything standard you can think of doesn't work. Booting into Safe Mode has no effect, and `dwm.exe` cannot be effectively terminated (the other system processes can't really be effectively terminated either) in order to delete these files.

This is a thought experiment to replicate (mentally, don't try this) whats happening here.

If you were to go into C:\Windows\System32, and start trying to delete DLL's the OS needs to run, you would get errors saying something like "File In Use - The action can't be completed because the file is open in . . .", where '. . .' would be some system process like dwm.exe, explorer.exe, etc.

However, instead of these DLL's being in System32, you have 20 **copies** of them on your Desktop, but if you wan't to delete these 20 copies, you will get the same message as if you were trying to delete the real ones in System32.

Comment: Found a tool called Pendmoves. It allows to schedule file move/remove during the next time the system reboots. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556.aspx

Comment: Unregister the dll's before you change ownership-permissions on the files.

Comment: @Moab Please read people's questions before providing irrelevant criticism. This has nothing to do with permissions. Thanks anyway.

Comment: edited comment after i put my glasses on.............since you gave no screenshots or quotes of the error messages when you attempt to delete we have no idea of the real issue. Please revise your question with more detailed information.

Comment: Well I added some more detail, it may be a bit more clear. Permissions are fine, it's just the the OS is convinced it is using all of these DLL's the same as it would be using system DLL's located in System32. In the InstallAware output folders, there's somewhere around 20 copies of these DLL's, and the OS is most definitely _not_ using all of these simultaneously for the same purpose.

Comment: Perhaps the thought experiment helps

Comment: I think if you unregister the dll's using the command prompt you should be able to delete them.

Comment: Since they are system DLL's I don't believe they have an entry point for unregistration.